# Restore Void Linux Install after breaking it by updating after 18 months

Tags: software-updates, void-linux, powerpc

I have an old Apple PowerBook on which I dual boot Void Linux and Mac OSX Leopard. I had some hardware problems around July 2021 and it took until now for me to get it fixed.

When I got it working again, it booted straight into Void Linux and I (unwisely) decided to run the `sudo xbps-install -Su` command to get it back up to date. I got the message that xbps needed to update first so I ran the appropriate command and then `sudo xbps-install -Su`again.

The update began running as normal but then I started getting error messages about things breaking like NTP daemon and WPA supplicant.

Now it won't boot into a graphical environment (it was booting into Mate) but hangs at loading b43 firmware version 666.2 after about 35 seconds.

If I use ctrl-alt-f1 at this point I can get to a command line interface and log in but then there are repeated error messages `openntpd[2732]:segfault (11) at 4 nip a7b63f74 lr 74f4dc code 1 in libc-2.32.so[a7a2f0001c2000]...` These keep repeating with different numbers but only if the ethernet cable is plugged in.

I would be grateful for any advice on salvaging the install, I had it working really nicely and the hardware problem was unrelated to the Void Install. Or is it better just to start again?

Sadly, the Void PPC port has just been deprecated this month so this would be a temporary solution while I decide what to install instead...

Comment: Exactly what are the error messages for ntp? Please edit the question to include them.

Comment: I've used void for a few years, and honestly I would just backup the existing home and etc directories, blow the old installation away, and reinstall. I'm actually in a pretty similar position to you, my old laptop died a couple of years ago. I'm not going to worry about resurrecting it, just rip the hard drive out, back it up, and when I get a new laptop do a fresh build. It's not worth the struggle to fix a rolling release distro that hasn't been updated for a long time.

Comment: This looks like good advice, the only possible issue is that the last images for PowerPC were released in August 2021, just a month after my computer originally stopped working.